# Serializing swing/awt components

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jpanel

I am trying to serialize a JPanel but everytime i get this error:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.GroupLayout
```

Can you tell me, what could be the problem or what is the proper way of serializing it.

What i do is pretty simple:

FOR Serializing:

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("myfile.dat");
ObjectOutputStream ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
Object object = panel;  //where panel is a JPanel type object
ostream.writeObject(object);
ostream.close();
```

And now for deserializing:

```
File file = new File("myfile.dat");
ObjectInputStream in;
try {
   in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
   object = (JPanel) in.readObject();
   in.close();
} catch (Exception e2) {
   e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

while reading the serialized object in last step i encounter the above error. What is the reason, or any idea how is should do this?

Comment: It would be better to serialize data about the panel, or the values of the children (text fields, combos, lists etc.), than the panel itself.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, yes but it is way to complex for me to go about picking each object in the panel, panel itself is part of JUNG framework and is called visualization viewer which apparently extends JPanel

Answer (score 3):

JPanel implements Serializable...

But javax.swing.GroupLayout don't.

So, you need to change GroupLayout to another layout class!

Answer (score 3):

`GroupLayout`, which appears to have been added to the panel, is not serialisable. There are a few options (listed least to most favourable).

- Subclass `GroupLayout` to create a serial proxy (see Effective Java 2nd Ed). This is a fair bit of work, and is complicated by `GroupLayout` not having a complete set of "getters and setters".
- Replace `GroupLayout` with a serialisable `LayoutManager`. There's the functional but rough `GridBagLayout` in the Java library. Other layout managers are available.
- Don't serialise the `JPanel`. Making AWT components serialisable (and the whole JavaBeans thing) was a laughable mistake.

Comment: +1 for the 3rd bullet. Straight from JPanel's API: `Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases`

Answer (score 2):

To be serializeable the object (and all the parts of it with exception of the POJOs) needs to implement the Serializable interface.

If you cannot change the class, take a look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Comment: the class does implements serializeable interface:  implements java.io.Serializable but the error is the same

Comment: javax.swing.GroupLayout does not implement it. Try adding a transient to it.

Comment: Ok i try it, actually it is not a panel really but a class that extends panel and comes from external library so would require lot of manual changes, but i try now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

To serialize an object, all the objects it references need to also be serializable aswell. You can mark a reference `transient` if you don't want it to be serialized. This means, if your panel refers to objects which are not serilizable, make them serilizable aswell or mark them `transient`

Comment: interesting, im gonna try will get back if i get some problem