# Deserialized JPanel's components lost their event listeners

Tags: java, swing, serialization, netbeans

I am working on a swing project that involves the user saving the state of the current `JPanel` he is working with, and being able to load it back on another tab in a tabbed pane, the image below shows the application's interface:

[image: Image show the application's initial interface]

While running the application, newer components are added to the current panel dynamically based on the user's actions on the existing components, this means these existing components as well as newer components have event listeners and they are working. See image below:

[image: Image showing changes in the interface based on user's actions]

As you can see there are different panels in a Tabbed Pane, the current Panel will be serialized when the user clicks the save menu item in the file menu, and it will be loaded back on the tabbed pane's tab titled "Load Saved Algorithm".

I learned the hard way that I WILL NOT be able to serialize a JPanel that was designed with NetBeans drag & drop GUI builder because the Layout Manager that NetBeans uses is `GroupLayout` and `GroupLayout` is unfortunately not Serializable!

However I have designed the application almost to the final stage so changing the Layout Manager is NOT an option. I searched SO for solutions and discovered this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874304/serializing-swing-awt-components#9874344) which talks about [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html).

So I decided to use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/index.html), I followed their tutorial and did the serialization and the deserialization successfully see image below:

[image: Image showing loaded panel]

Now the problem is, after deserialization I discovered that the components are no longer responding to user inputs/events. Please I need help, either another better alternative to serializing non-serializable objects or a solution to the obvious problem.

Here is my code for serialization:

```
public void savePanel() throws IOException
{
    int selectedIndex = this.parentTabPan.getSelectedIndex();
    JPanel panelTobeSaved = new JPanel();
    switch(selectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            panelTobeSaved = this.linearTabPanel;
            break;
        case 1:
            panelTobeSaved = this.quadraticTabPanel;
            break;
        case 2:
            panelTobeSaved = this.unconstranedTabPanel;
            break;
        case 3:
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please select an algorithm tab.", "Access Denied", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            break;
        case 4:
            panelTobeSaved = this.loadSavedPanel;
            break;
    }

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        File newFile = null;
        String fileName = file.getName();
        if(!fileName.contains(".") && fileChooser.getFileFilter() instanceof FileNameExtensionFilter)
        {
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = (FileNameExtensionFilter)fileChooser.getFileFilter();
            newFile = new File(file.getPath()+"."+(filter.getExtensions())[0]);
            fileName = newFile.getName();
            System.out.println(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            newFile = file;
            System.out.println(newFile.getName());
        }
        System.out.println(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
        try
        {
            XStream xstream = new XStream();
            String xml = xstream.toXML(panelTobeSaved);
            // if file doesn't exists, then create it
            if(!newFile.exists())
                newFile.createNewFile();
            try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newFile.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);)
            {
                out.print(xml);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException xcp)
        {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, xcp.getMessage(), "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            xcp.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

and deserialization:

```
private void openMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    if(evt.getSource() == this.openMenuItem)
    {
        int returnValue = this.fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File file = this.fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            try(FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
                in.read(data);
                String xml = new String(data);
                XStream xstream = new XStream();
                JPanel restoredPanel = (JPanel)xstream.fromXML(xml);
                this.parentTabPan.removeTabAt(4);
                this.parentTabPan.addTab("Load Saved Algorithm", restoredPanel);
                this.parentTabPan.setSelectedIndex(4);
            }
            catch(IOException xcp)
            {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, xcp.getMessage(), "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                xcp.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the listeners deserialized as well?

Comment: I can't tell, but I think they are not because the components aren't responding.

Comment: Well if everything isn't deserialized and put back in the correct place then you'll have issues. If you think you have that issue I'd start looking there.