# How to serialize Object with JFrame inside and transfer it via network

Tags: java, swing, sockets, serialization

I have object Client, which has JFrame inside. I need to transfer Client via network, but JFrame contains a lot of UI objects such as text fields, buttons etc. When I try to do it I get `java.io.NotSerializableException`. I declared my JFrame as Serializable, but I will not to create custom UI objects to do it for each. How I can transfer my Client with JFrame inside via network? I found some solutions, but they all applicable for JFrame only, but not for more complex object.

Comment: All the objects that is used in the class must be serializable.

Comment: @Braj I undestand it, but I think, that creating custom serializable object for every case (jbutton, jtext etc) it is not good. I hope, that somebody found better solution.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't serialise graphics components, especially to transmit across the wire, there are issues associated with the native peer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have to. `JFrame` extends [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html), which is serializable. Same goes for the other AWT/Swing components. If you're extending existing component classes to create your own, most likely you'll just need to declare a `serialVersionUID` in your classes, and you should be fine.

Comment: But javax.swing.GroupLayout is not.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. The same issue is also discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874304/serializing-swing-awt-components